# Logic App failure: Effective identity on Azure SQL datasources with SSO enabled requires access token to be provided

Tags: azure-logic-apps, power-automate

3 days ago one of my Logic Apps started failing.

I re-created it from blank with only the step that fails and the same issue occurs.

Step: Power BI: Export To File for Paginated Reports

Error:

```
{
"statusCode": 400,
"headers": {
    "Pragma": "no-cache",
    "Strict-Transport-Security": "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains",
    "X-Frame-Options": "deny",
    "X-Content-Type-Options": "nosniff",
    "RequestId": "xxxxxxx",
    "Access-Control-Expose-Headers": "RequestId",
    "Timing-Allow-Origin": "*",
    "x-ms-apihub-cached-response": "false",
    "Cache-Control": "no-store, must-revalidate, no-cache",
    "Date": "Wed, 26 Jan 2022 13:17:19 GMT",
    "Content-Length": "170",
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
},
"body": {
    "error": {
        "code": "InvalidRequest",
        "message": "Effective identity on Azure SQL datasources with SSO enabled requires access token to be provided"
    }
}
}
```

I'm using an account that has full admin access, only used for automation jobs. The account can run the report manually just fine.

Googling the error comes up with no results.

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't have an answer but reading up a bit (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/reports/export-to-file#paginatedreportexportconfiguration, click on `EffectiveIdentity` which takes you to here ... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/reports/export-to-file#effectiveidentity) ... there's an `Identities` parameter that you may need to fill if you're not already.  Just a thought.  I see it in the action in Logic Apps.

Comment: I tried that before submitting this and the error was different: "Exporting a paginated report with an effective identity with reports is not supported"

Comment: I’d be raising that with Microsoft directly then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed issue by clicking( ... ) next to the report(s) in question, selecting Manage and selecting the same auth type as the report (SQL or Oauth2) and re entering the same creds that were used for the report.